# ColorTranslator exists in both System.Drawing.Common and System.Drawing.Primitives

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

The type 'ColorTranslator' exists in both 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' and 'System.Drawing.Primitives, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I have seen this error on google, stackoverflow, microsoft but all solutions don't work with me and increase the bugginess of the error.

Comment: Can you show the contents of your csproj file in the question?  Adding any additional relevant information could also help.